# How to not loose dynamically appended Data inside table after reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my JavaScript Code. It is working fine but the inserted data which I inserted dynamically inside the table lost after reloading. I am also doing Server Side validation so I don't want to loose the dynamically added Data after the Page Reload.

```
function AddItem() {
        debugger;
        if (validate() == false) {
            return false;
        }

        var ItemId = $("#Item").val();
        var Item = $("#Item").find(":selected").text();

        var Batch = $("#Batch").val();
        var Quantity = $("#Quantity").val();
        var BonusIncluded = $("#BonusIncluded").val();
        var CostPrice = $("#CostPrice").val();
        var SellingPrice = $("#SellingPrice").val();
        var ExpiryDate = $("#ExpiryDate").val();

        var i = $("#tbody tr").length;
        var inputItem = i + "inputItem"
        var AppendCode = '';
        AppendCode += "<tr id = '" + i + "table'> "
        AppendCode += "<td> <input type = 'hidden' name= 'PurchaseReturnItems[" + i + "].ItemID' value = '" + ItemId + "' id= '" + i + "Item' class = 'form-control " + inputItem + "' readonly /> " + Item + " </td>"
        AppendCode += "<td> <input type = 'text' name = 'PurchaseReturnItems[" + i + "].Batch' value = '" + Batch + "' id= '" + i + "Batch' class = 'form-control " + inputItem + "' readonly /> </td>"
        AppendCode += "<td> <input type = 'number' min='1' name= 'PurchaseReturnItems[" + i + "].Qty'  value = '" + Quantity + "' id= '" + i + "Quantity' class = 'form-control " + inputItem + "' readonly  /></td>"
        AppendCode += "<td> <input type = 'number' min='1' name = 'PurchaseReturnItems[" + i + "].BonusIncluded' value = '" + BonusIncluded + "' id= '" + i + "BonusIncluded' class = 'form-control " + inputItem + "' readonly /> </td>"
        AppendCode += "<td> <input type = 'number' name = 'PurchaseReturnItems[" + i + "].CostPrice' min = '1' value = '" + CostPrice + "' id= '" + i + "CostPrice' class = 'form-control " + inputItem + "' readonly/> "
        AppendCode += "</td> <td> <input type = 'number' min = '1' name = 'PurchaseReturnItems[" + i + "].SellingPrice' value = '" + SellingPrice + "' id= '" + i + "SellingPrice' class = 'form-control " + inputItem + "' readonly />"
        AppendCode += "</td> <td> <input type = 'date' min = '1' name = 'PurchaseReturnItems[" + i + "].Expiry' value = '" + ExpiryDate + "' id= '" + i + "ExpiryDate' class = 'form-control " + inputItem + "' readonly /> </td>"
        AppendCode += "<td> <button type= 'button' id = '" + i + "editBtn' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' onclick=' return EditRow(" + i + ")'><span class='fa fa-edit'></span></button>"
        AppendCode += "<button id = '" + i + "deleteBtn' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' onclick='return DeleteRow(" + i + ", " + ItemId + ")'><span class='fa fa-close'></span></button>"
        AppendCode += "<button style = 'display:none;' id = '" + i + "confirmBtn' class='btn btn-sm btn-success' onclick='return ConfirmRow(" + i + ")'><span class='fa fa-check'></span></button>"
        AppendCode += "<input type = 'text'  id='" + i + "IsDelete' value='0' name= PurchaseReturnItems[" + i + "].IsDelete</td> </tr>"
        $("#tbody").append(AppendCode);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

unless you saved the dynamic data in DB/Session/Cookie you can't get it working as HTTP is stateless. on refresh, you're initiating a new HTTP request which won't bother your previous client data unless you send them with HTTP request and save the table data for next request.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a persistence module that will save the data in the table. meaning that on every add/remove action or on page unload you should save the table's state in something persistent.

you can do this using Cookies, IndexedDB ,LocalStorage or even on you server. there many tools used for persistence, just pick one.

a very very rough method to do it is to save all of the tbody's content to persistence module and when loading the page if the data is available then fill the table.

if you want to get more granular, save only the important fields like in a DB and on page load rebuild the table according to the available fields.